# How to upload image by REST api (without base64) magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, image, rest-api, upload

I try to upload an image by rest API in Magento 1.9 version but getting "invalid content-type' error.

Can any one help me for the same?

Comment: please check your content type like : ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’

Comment: Not getting your point exactly, all other API is working only image upload not working or in other words if i set "multipart/form-data" in content-type then i get above error.

Comment: @VishalBansal Have you got any solution for uplaod image via rest api without base64 ?